# how to push project to local git repository with intelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I swapped from svn to git and have problems to initially
import my project files to the created git repository.

So I have project x and use

```
VCS -> Import into Version Control -> create Git Repositroy
```

*new empty repository created*

```
(path to git repo /foo/bar)
(path to project /elsewhere
```

Question: **How to push my project into this repository**

When I use Push... (ctrl + shift + k)
a popup occurs whichs says

*master -> empty repository*

and when I try to use

VCS -> Git -> Checkin Directory it says:

*No changes detected*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistake to not create the git repository 
at my project's root (svn habbit's).

solved by :

```
VCS -> Import into Version Control -> create Git Repositroy
```

*Select directory where the new Git repositoty will be created:*

```
/path/to/project
```

now I can commit the files and 
push them to a remote repository

Answer (score 1):

Pushing is an operation of moving changes from one repository to another. In this case, there is only one repository, so there's nothing to push.

To put your files into the repository, you need to add them using "Git | Add..." action in the context menu or using the Changes view, and then commit them using the "Commit Changes" action. That's it.

Comment: but it always states : no changes detected

Comment: It will say "No changes detected" if you did not add any files to the repository. You need to add the files

Comment: does the repos has to be in the same directory as the project ?

Comment: Yes, it has to be in the same directory.

Comment: so I have to create the git repositroy at the project root; I thought 
I could sepperate the working directory and my repositroy